# The fraction entry, found in the comment of an answer, doesn't appear correctly in the app

Tags: bug, ios-app

The limits are not different. The first form is just a indeterminate limit of the kind $\frac00$, this mean that you need some manipulation to get the value for this limit.

- App Version: 1.5.0.3
- Device: iPhone 5 (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 9.3.2 (Build 13F69)

Comment: Can  you add some screenshots to illustrate your problem, as it is not very clear what you mean?